# Asp.Net Core running SignalR in multiple browser tabs

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core Application running on 4.7 with an Angular front-end. As I need to notify the users about status changes I'm trying to add SignalR. I'm using following versions:

- AspNetCore 2.0.1
- Angular 5.x
- SignalR 1.0.0-alpha2-final

Below you can see my code. If I run this app I can see in the logs that both hub connections get started. If I open a second browser tab with the same URL, only one connection is successful. For the second hub I always get this error:

```
Error: Not Found
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYload] (http://localhost:51616/dist/estructuring_main.js?v=fBx34vrzWnqBIPjAm71NaWQz0TEeQZWcx2ixKnjADWI:36168:28)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (http://localhost:51616/dist/vendor.js?v=rp1X6LsN5SJnsTJrd-749xunuUaKAA_WINwoqzbaeqE:120085:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:51616/dist/vendor.js?v=rp1X6LsN5SJnsTJrd-749xunuUaKAA_WINwoqzbaeqE:119340:31) 
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:51616/dist/vendor.js?v=rp1X6LsN5SJnsTJrd-749xunuUaKAA_WINwoqzbaeqE:5013:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:51616/dist/vendor.js?v=rp1X6LsN5SJnsTJrd-749xunuUaKAA_WINwoqzbaeqE:119339:36)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:51616/dist/vendor.js?v=rp1X6LsN5SJnsTJrd-749xunuUaKAA_WINwoqzbaeqE:119107:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:51616/dist/vendor.js?v=rp1X6LsN5SJnsTJrd-749xunuUaKAA_WINwoqzbaeqE:119415:34)
    at invokeTask (http://localhost:51616/dist/vendor.js?v=rp1X6LsN5SJnsTJrd-749xunuUaKAA_WINwoqzbaeqE:120436:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:51616/dist/vendor.js?v=rp1X6LsN5SJnsTJrd-749xunuUaKAA_WINwoqzbaeqE:120462:17)
```

The error says 404 not found even though I can see the request in my request-middleware.

What do I need to change that the hub connections also work with multiple tabs?

`Startup.cs`

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(IUserTracker<>), typeof(InMemoryUserTracker<>));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<StatusHub>("status", (options) =>
            {
                options.Transports = TransportType.LongPolling;
            });

            routes.MapHub<AutopricerHub>("autopricer", (options) =>
            {
                options.Transports = TransportType.LongPolling;
            });
        });
    }
```

`InMemoryUserTracker.cs`

```
    public class InMemoryUserTracker<THub> : IUserTracker<THub>
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<HubConnectionContext, UserDetails> usersOnline
            = new ConcurrentDictionary<HubConnectionContext, UserDetails>();

        public IEnumerable<UserDetails> UsersOnline()
            => usersOnline.Values.AsEnumerable();

        public Task AddUser(HubConnectionContext connection, UserDetails userDetails)
        {
            usersOnline.TryAdd(connection, userDetails);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task RemoveUser(HubConnectionContext connection)
        {
            usersOnline.TryRemove(connection, out var userDetails);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

`BaseHubWithPresence.cs`

```
    public abstract class BaseHubWithPresence : Hub
    {
        protected readonly IUserTracker<BaseHubWithPresence> userTracker;

        protected BaseHubWithPresence(IUserTracker<BaseHubWithPresence> userTracker)
        {
            this.userTracker = userTracker;
        }

        public virtual async Task Join(long userId)
        {
            await userTracker.AddUser(Context.Connection, new UserDetails(Context.ConnectionId, userId));
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public virtual async Task Leave()
        {
            await userTracker.RemoveUser(Context.Connection);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

`AutopricerHub.cs`

```
    public class AutopricerHub : BaseHubWithPresence
    {
        public AutopricerHub(IUserTracker<AutopricerHub> userTracker)
           : base(userTracker) {}

        public async Task SendToAll()
        {
            await Clients.All.InvokeAsync("All", "data");
        }

        public async Task SendUpdateAsync(long userId)
        {
            foreach (var user in userTracker.UsersOnline().Where(o => o.UserId == userId))
            {
                await Clients.Client(user.ConnectionId).InvokeAsync("Update", "data");
            }
        }
    }
```

`StatusHub.cs`

```
    public class StatusHub : BaseHubWithPresence
    {
        public StatusHub(IUserTracker<BaseHubWithPresence> userTracker)
           : base(userTracker)
        {
        }

        public async Task SendSingleAsync(long listener)
        {
            foreach (var user in userTracker.UsersOnline().Where(o => o.UserId == listener))
            {
                await Clients.Client(user.ConnectionId).InvokeAsync("Update", "data");
            }
        }

        public async Task SendMultipleAsync(IReadOnlyCollection<long> listeners)
        {
            foreach (var listener in listeners)
            {
                foreach (var user in userTracker.UsersOnline().Where(o => o.UserId == listener))
                {
                    await Clients.Client(user.ConnectionId).InvokeAsync("Update", "data");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`price-notification.service.ts`

```
    @Injectable()
    export class PriceNotificationService {
        private hubConnection: HubConnection;
        private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

        constructor(
            private appContextService: AppContextService,
            private messageService: MessageService) { 

            this.init();
        }

        private init(): void {
            this.hubConnection = new HubConnection('/autopricer', { transport: TransportType.LongPolling });

            this.hubConnection.start()
                .then(() => {
                    this.appContextService.getAppContext().takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe(appContext => {
                        this.hubConnection.invoke('join', appContext.FirmuserId);
                    });
                    DEBUG.init && debug('Price Notification Hub connection started');
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    DEBUG.init && debug('Error while establishing Price Notification Hub connection');
                });

            this.hubConnection.onclose = e => {
                DEBUG.functionCalls && debug('On close Price Notification Hub connection');
                this.hubConnection.invoke('leave');
            };

            this.hubConnection.off('leave', null);
        }

        private showUpdateNotification(data: string) {

        }

        private showAllNotification(data: string) {

        }
    }
```

`status-notification.service.ts`

```
    @Injectable()
    export class StatusNotificationService {
        private hubConnection: HubConnection;
        private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

        constructor(
            private appContextService: AppContextService,
            private messageService: MessageService) {

            this.init();
        }

        private init(): void {
            this.hubConnection = new HubConnection('/status', { transport: TransportType.LongPolling });

            this.hubConnection.start()
                .then(() => {
                    this.appContextService.getAppContext().takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe(appContext => {
                        this.hubConnection.invoke('join', appContext.FirmuserId);
                    });
                    DEBUG.init && debug('Status Notification Hub connection started');
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    DEBUG.init && debug('Error while establishing Status Notification Hub connection');
                });

            this.hubConnection.onclose = e => {
                DEBUG.functionCalls && debug('On close Status Notification Hub connection');
                this.hubConnection.invoke('leave');
            };

            this.hubConnection.off('leave', null);
        }

        private showUpdateNotification(data: string) {

        }
    }
```

The service provider for each of these Angular service is in a separate component.

Browser `network` tab:
[image]

Comment: What's on your `network` tab in the browser? we got this working no problem, it was a range of session tracking, LB cookies and related issues that bit us, ended up overriding a bunch of code before it became stable

Comment: @zaitsman added a pricture, it seems that other requests get blocket and reaching the server after after sometimes more than 20 secs.

Comment: @Dani Did you test it also which another browser

Comment: @Tester Yes, Chrome 65 and Firefox 52.5.2 (this is the official browser)

Comment: @zaitsman What exactly did you override?

Comment: You need sticky sessions enabled in multi server scenarios

Comment: @davidfowl I run only one IIS instance or do I get you wrong?

Comment: I see, then I have no idea how you're getting a 404. What does the response body say

Comment: @davidfowl The response is: "No Connection with that ID" which makes sense because it is a new connection. But why is the framework expecting an existing connection?

Comment: Which line is the error on?